# How to limit the number of registers used by each thread in Numba (CUDA)

Tags: python, cuda, numba

as the title says I would like to know if there is a way to limit the number of registers used by each thread when I launch a kernel.
I'm performing a lot of computation on each thread and so the number of registers used is too high and then the occupancy is low. I would like to try to reduce the number of registers used in order to try to improve parallel thread execution, maybe at the cost of more memory accesses.

I searched for the answer but I didn't find a solution. I think that is possible to set a maximum number of registers used by thread with the CUDA toolchain, but is it also possible when using Numba?

EDIT: Maybe also forcing a minimum numbers of blocks to be executed in a multi processor in order to force the compiler to reduce the number of used registers.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the `cuda.jit` facility offered by numba does not allow passing of arguments to the CUDA assembler which would allow control of register allocation, as is possible with the native CUDA toolchain.

So I don't think there is a way to do what you have asked about.

Comment: It seems there is a way to do this now, refer to `max_registers` [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda-reference/kernel.html)